# почему анимация продолжает загружаться снова и снова при скролле?

Tags: javascript, html, css, запрос

я хотела сделать так, чтобы все буквы пошли обрато в смои места при `$(window).scrollTop>150`, но они идут обрато только если продолжать прокручивать страницу вниз, а когда стоишь на месте они опять строются в линию.

помогите?

```js
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.letters').removeClass('hidden');
  }, 600)


  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (top > 150) {
      $('.letters').addClass('hidden')
    }
  });




})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}

.welcome {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.letters {
  font-size: 6em;
  font-weight: 200;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 15%;
  color: white;
}

.letters li {
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 50px;
  transition: all 3s ease
}

.letters.hidden li {
  opacity: 0;
}

.letters.hidden li:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(-200px, 200px);
}

.letters.hidden li:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate(200px, -240px);
}

.letters.hidden li:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(300px, 300px);
}

.letters.hidden li:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translate(-180px, -280px);
}

.letters.hidden li:nth-child(5) {
  transform: translate(450px, 10px);
}

.letters.hidden li:nth-child(6) {
  transform: translate(40px, -310px);
}

.letters.hidden li:nth-child(7) {
  transform: translate(60px, 170px);
}

.content {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="welcome">
  <ul class="letters hidden">
    <li>W</li>
    <li>E</li>
    <li>L</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>O</li>
    <li>M</li>
    <li>E</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">

</div>
```

Comment: Ну так потопу что выше 150, все время отвечает true, добавьте проверку отработали ли она.

Comment: как мне это сделать? можете обьяснить?

Comment: Еще раз, хочу уточнить, когда я поднимаюсь вверх буквы должны стать на место, если просколировал более 150 должны уйти и более не появляться?

Comment: да да, все верно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {

  setInterval(function() {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (top < 150) {
      $('.letters').removeClass('hidden');
    }
  }, 600)


  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (top > 150) {
      $('.letters').addClass('hidden')
    } else {
      $('.letters').removeClass('hidden')
    }
  });




})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.welcome {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.letters {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: 200;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}

.letters li {
  display: inline-block;
  //letter-spacing: 50px;
  transition: all 3s ease
}

.letters.hidden li {
  opacity: 0;
}

.letters.hidden li:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(-200px, 200px);
}

.letters.hidden li:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate(200px, -240px);
}

.letters.hidden li:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(300px, 300px);
}

.letters.hidden li:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translate(-180px, -280px);
}

.letters.hidden li:nth-child(5) {
  transform: translate(450px, 10px);
}

.letters.hidden li:nth-child(6) {
  transform: translate(40px, -310px);
}

.letters.hidden li:nth-child(7) {
  transform: translate(60px, 170px);
}

.content {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="welcome">
  <ul class="letters hidden">
    <li>W</li>
    <li>E</li>
    <li>L</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>O</li>
    <li>M</li>
    <li>E</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">

</div>
```

Comment: ой погодите, а как сделать так, чтобы буквы появлялись сразу после загрузки экрана, а не как тут, после движения экрана?

Comment: Поправил, и немного поправил позиционирование

Comment: ок, спасибо большое!!

Comment: Я бы еще посоветовал добавить для `.letters`  ` overflow: hidden;`, тогда буквы которые вылетят за блок не будут отображаться.

Comment: хорошо, сделаю. кстати про позиционирование.. оно у меня как то криво отображается. все ли верно? не понимаю:(

Comment: У всех :) Я думал у вас глобально стили спрошены,  нужно убрать у ul падинг и маржин. Я в примере поправил, и буквы меньше кину, чтобы входили.

Comment: ок, отлично! Благодарю)